# MongoDB sort order on timestamp / ISODate fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting

If there is a MongoDB collection that contains documents with field `foo` with both integer timestamps and `ISODate` objects, what will the resulting order of a sorted query be?

Will one of the objects come before the other, or will they be compared and interleaved?

The reason I ask is because this is true in Javascript (see below), but I'm wondering what will happen in MongoDB's underlying implementation.

```js
> new Date(400) <= 401
true
> new Date(401) <= 400
false
```

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#behaviors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does type checking and conversion for certain comparison and not for all of them. I would suggest looking further in the documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#behaviors to see how the sort behaves in ordering when the types are different.